# Tried triple boot and Windows 7 no longer boots

Tags: windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I had a system with 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium installed and I installed first Fedora 64-bit alongside it. Then I decided I can do triple boot and installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit using manual partitioning without altering anything about Windows partitions. I tried to boot Windows 7, but it did not work; however, Ubuntu works fine. How can I restore Windows 7?

Comment: can you include your partition table and the config file of your bootloader (grub or lilo)?

Comment: I actually tried to fix the MBR using a Windows recovery disk and this time all the GRUB 2 disappeared. I think somehow I installed GRUB alongside Windows bootloader now there are Fedora 20 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my computer already installed but there is no GRUB. What can I do?

Comment: windows recovery deletes grub from your MBR, you shouldn't have done that. you now have to boot your computer into a linux live disk and chroot into the fedora partition, for example 'chroot /dev/sda2'. now you have to reinstall grub 'grub-install /dev/hda'. after this you have working fedora and windows (I hope).

Comment: @switch87 Thanks, but I also have Ubuntu installed. My aim is to have a triple boot system.

Comment: I know, but it's a start to undo your mistake, get grub working again, than we can work on your tripple boot.

Comment: @switch87 Yeah thanks for your help. I will try it tomorrow when I am less prone to make mistakes. I will keep you updated.

Comment: For future reference, before doing stuff that can overwrite your MBR you should make a backup of it. This is easy to do using `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Boot-repair to fix Windows-Linux:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

If you can't run from Ubuntu it's easy to make bootable disk, run the repair program on it.